# How to make Endeca support AL32UTF8 character set instead of UTF8?

Tags: java, utf-8, atg, endeca

Endeca supports UTF8 by default and we have encoded certain special characters to UTF8 to be accepted by Endeca while we query. Our customer now requires database to support AL32UTF8 character set. We checked our database and it supports AL32UTF8 character set.

While our Endeca supports UTF8, how can we change Endeca to support AL32UTF8 character set now. Also, we need to change the code in java to do AL32UTF8 encoding to be accepted by Endeca.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Interesting question! I'd like to know a few more things: Are you using ATG+Endeca? Which versions of each? Do you know which deployment template you are using for Endeca? Are you using the Deployment Template for Product Catalog Integration? For Endeca, are you using CAS only, or are you using Forge as well or Forge only?

Comment: @chairbender, we are using ATG+Endeca. ATG version is 10.2 and Endeca version for CAS (3.1.2), MDEX(6.4.1) , Platformservices(6.1.3) and ToolsAndFramework (3.1.2). For Endeca we are using Forge as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to ***Chapter 4*** **Character Encoding** of [I18N Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51272_02/Common.110/pdf/InternationalizationGuide.pdf).

Comment: thanks for giving the reference. I checked chapter 4 and we have used the same way of encoding to UTF-8 in our code. What I came to know is we need to create the manipulator for using character set other than UTF-8 if using Forge. Is it actually required or we can change the code to encode to AL32UTF8 instead of UTF8 and endeca will accept it??